# use split -d on macOS bash

Tags: split

When on linux `split -d` can be used as a numeric suffixes starting at 0, so like having

```
split -d -l 1500 ${TEMP_FILE} ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    mv "${DATADIR}/${DATASET}/user_artists00" "${DATADIR}/${DATASET}/user_artists.train"
    mv "${DATADIR}/${DATASET}/user_artists01" "${DATADIR}/${DATASET}/user_artists.test"
```

but on `macOS` the `-d` option it is missing. According to man we have

```
 -a suffix_length
             Use suffix_length letters to form the suffix of the file name.
```

and it is stated

> If additional arguments are specified, the first is used as the name of the input file which is to be split.  If a second additional argument is speci-
>            fied, it is used as a prefix for the names of the files into which the file is split.  In this case, each file into which the file is split is named by
>            the prefix followed by a lexically ordered suffix using suffix_length characters in the range ``a-z''.  If -a is not specified, two letters are used as
>            the suffix.

so in my understanding I cannot have as output file something like $MYINPUT00, $MYINPUT01, etc, while only `xaa`, `xab`, etc. by defaults, since `-a` only admits a `[a-z]` range.

Comment: What's the relationship between `TEMP_FILE` and `OUTPUT_FILE` and the hardcoded names? What is your actual question? If you only expect two output files, renaming `xaa` instead of `00` etc would seem like a trivial and obvious workaround. Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions but perhaps you have one in mind here?

Comment: `-d` is a GNU extension to its implementation of `split`. You would have to install the GNU version on macOS, which ships with the BSD version.

Comment: @tripleee the question was how to use `split` with a `-d` numeric suffix option in `macOS`. According to last comment this seems not to be possibile by the way without the `BSD` version of the command, since macOS version is `POSIX(1)` version.

Comment: You are confused; the MacOS userland is based on BSD and generally also conforms to POSIX; but the `-d` option is not defined in POSIX. Anyway, if "install GNU `split`" is an acceptable answer, this isn't really about programming.

Comment: @tripleee right I should move to the Unix & linux, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS `split` is `BSD split`, which is different than `GNU split`. `-d` is an extension of `GNU split`. So you cannot use numeric suffixes with `BSD split`.

However, if you really want to do it on macOS, you can write a simple additional script to make it work.

```sh
split -l "$linelimit" "$infile" "$prefix"
i=0
# to put "suffixlen" digits at the end
suffixlen=3
for file in "$prefix"*; do
    # to make 2 as 002 etc.
    suffix=$(printf "%0${suffixlen}d" $i)
    # actual renaming
    mv "$file" "$prefix$suffix"
    ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 7):

You can install `brew install coreutils` with Homebrew and invoke the GNU split `gsplit` instead to use the `-d` argument.